# replace specific range of numbers with NA

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, na

I am dealing with a dataframe that has some unacceptable numbers in one of its columns. I am wondering how I can replace numbers in a specific range with NA value in R?
so for example

```
> V1 <- c(23,2,4)
> V2 <- c(7,2,9)
> V3 <- c(23,2,9)
> df <- data.frame(V1, V2, V3)
    
           V1   V2   V3
    [1,]   23    7   23
    [2,]    2    2    2
    [3,]    4    9    9
```

in this data frame, first I want to change all numbers more than 20 in column 1 to NA (because number more than 20 is not realistic for the data I have) and then take average of that column.

so the result dataframe would be :

```
       V1   V2   V3
[1,]   NA    7   23
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    4    9    9
```

and the average of the first column would be (2+4)/2=3

Comment: You need `mat[,1][mat[,1] > 20] <- NA` and then `mean(na.omit(mat[,1]))`

Comment: I am dealing with a data frame, is there any way to do what you mentioned on a data frame?

Comment: Yes, the code should work for data.frame column as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `base R` to do this.  Replace the elements in the first column that are greater than 20 to `NA` and get the `mean`

```
df[,1][df[,1] > 20] <- NA 
mean(df[,1], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 3
```

and for all the other columns

```
colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)
#     V1       V2       V3 
#3.00000  6.00000 11.33333
```

Or in a single line

```
mean(df[,1][df[,1] <= 20], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R solution:

```
colMeans(within(df, {V1 <- replace(V1, V1 > 20, NA_integer_)}), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
mat <- matrix(c(23,2,4,7,2,9,23,2,9), ncol = 3)
mat <- as.data.frame(mat)
#Solution for replace
mat %>% mutate(V1=ifelse(V1>20,NA,V1)) %>%
  colMeans(.,na.rm=T)
```

Output:

```
      V1       V2       V3 
 3.00000  6.00000 11.33333
```